# Save a time for later use

Tags: datetime

In the [datetime](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime) package, we have the command `\newdate`
which allows you to save a date for later use.

In the same line, without thinking much, I tried to use:
`\newtime{examstart}{09}{00}` and was rather surprised to 
find that this command does not exist.

A search reveals that actually there is nothing similar to 
`\newdate` for saving a time for later use.

What do you think will be the best way to save a time for later use?

Definitely, I will want to save the in some structured manner making further processing 
including formatting possible, just like the `\newdate` command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just mimick what `datetime` does for `\newtime`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newtime}[3]{%
  \@ifundefined{time@#1@h}
    {\@namedef{time@#1@h}{#2}\@namedef{time@#1@m}{#3}}
    {\PackageError{datetime}{Time `#1' already defined}{}}%
}
\newcommand{\displaytime}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{time@#1@h}
    {\PackageError{datetime}{Date `#1' not defined}{}}
    {\formattime{\@nameuse{time@#1@h}}{\@nameuse{time@#1@m}}{00}}%
}
\makeatother

\newtime{now}{15}{43}
\newtime{wow}{21}{12}

\begin{document}

\displaytime{now}

\displaytime{wow}

\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE displays `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \formattime 
                       {\@nameuse {time@now@h}}{\@nameuse {time@now@m}}{00}`

Comment: @MMA Check your version of `datetime`; I have version 2.59.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version solved the problem.

Comment: The new macro must be added to the next version of `datetime`.

Comment: @MMA Make a feature request to Nicola Talbot.

Comment: @MMA Just to add to egreg's comment, I have a [feature request form](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/feature-request.html).

Comment: Already submitted the request. Found via Google search.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Perhaps will want to add an _optional_ third argument for seconds as well.